# View PDF File in Unity iOS

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to open and view PDF file in iOS project. Following kind of code, I have tried upto now:

```
public void OnDel1ButtonClick ()
{
    Application.OpenURL ("file://" + Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/Del1.pdf");
}

public void OnDel2ButtonClick ()
{
    Application.OpenURL(Application.dataPath + "/Raw/Del1.pdf" );
//        Application.OpenURL ("file:///" + Application.streamingAssetsPath + "Del1.pdf");
}
```

I have placed PDF file in Streaming Assets folder like this:

[image]

Within Unity Editor, first button click event is working but within actual iPhone device none of the above ways are working. So give me some suggestion to open and view PDF file.

If any kind of permission, I was missing then also let me know about this. I have referred this document upto now:

[Streaming Assets](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html)

Comment: If you can host the pdf on a web server and open with https, it will be loaded in safari. Everything else does require some native coding, where you transfer the data to other pdf viewers like the Apples iBooks App. Otherwise another application can’t load the pdf file since it is in your safeguarded sandbox filesystem.

Comment: Basically this application/game does not doing anything related to server related thing. Just simple offline application. So what is way for me into this to view PDF file?

Comment: There are plugins you can buy, or you can spend a month developing your own. Likely you'd need to maybe look into Magick.Net and libs of the kind to convert your pdf to texture. There is no trick about pdf, it is a proprietary format from Adobe and it is not in Unity. If you really want it and you going to sell it, think about a plugin from asset store.

Comment: So without plugin either buy or develop from scratch, there is no way exist for me to view PDF files :(

Comment: Do you want to see the pdf inside or outside your application? And what should the user be able to do with it?

Comment: Basically PDF viewing can be inside or outside does not matter. Only users can view the PDF file. That is only purpose for me.

Comment: then you use a native iOS Plugin with inline webview like prime31.Etcetera, there are many solutions out there just google "unity ios webview", when opening the webview pass in your local file:// path, that should™ work.

Comment: So as per your saying, within WebView I can display game project PDF files.... right?

Comment: Yes that should work

Comment: I am experimenting same thing with this plugin: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/uniwebview-3-92605 - I wish, I will get success :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now let me post an answer so that this become useful to other users as well.
Thanks to @JeanLuc for your side guidance to reach at this conclusion.

I have used WebView to load my project stored PDF files. This plugin, I have used to put WebView inside project.

[UniWebView 3](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/uniwebview-3-92605)

Then after using following code, I can able to load PDF file that stored in StreamingAssets folder:

```
url = "file://" + Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/Del1.pdf";
UniWebView uniWebView = webview.GetComponent<UniWebView> ();
        uniWebView.zoomEnable = true;
        uniWebView.Reload ();
```

This answer become useful when PDF file present within game project.